# Logstash is skipping records while inserting records in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am new to elastic search. I am using to Logstash to push data from my PostgreSQL Database to elastic index. I usually set the `jdbc_page_size => 100000` in the config file for faster ingestion. However, data is not fully pushed even if logstash logs say all data has been pushed. So, I set `jdbc_page_size => 25000`, which solves my problem

I am facing this problem particularly with PostgesSQL(not with MySQL or MS SQL Server). If anyone has any insight, please clarify why this is happening.

EDIT :
Config File as requested:

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://ip:5432/dbname"
jdbc_user => "postgres"
jdbc_password => "postgres"
jdbc_driver_library => "/postgresql.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
jdbc_paging_enabled => true
jdbc_page_size => 25000
statement => "select * from source_table"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "localhost:9200"
index => "sample"
document_type => "docs"
document_id => "%{id}"
}
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you run `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool/bulk,index?v&h=id,name,active,rejected,completed` and do you see any errors in the ES logs?

Comment: I am not getting any error . Active and Rejected values are 0.

Comment: What about completed?

Comment: name  active rejected completed\
bulk       0        0   1725905
index      0        0         1
bulk       0        0   2044705
index      0        0        12
S1VEM5x-RAG7FHlsZ2hrvA bulk       0        0   1980739
S1VEM5x-RAG7FHlsZ2hrvA index      0        0        17

Comment: Non zero Values for completed

Comment: So, in order to deduce that not all values have been pushed, you're comparing the number of docs in ES with the number of records in your DB, right? How is your logstash pipeline configured?

Comment: Yes. I have inserted the de-normalised data in a separate table. 
#   pipeline:
#     batch:
#       size: 125
#       delay: 5

Comment: Can you update your question with your Logstash config file?

Comment: I have added the file. Please have a look.

Comment: How many docs are missing?

Comment: For a dataset of 20 Lacs, only 13 Lacs got pushed in elastic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not give records in same order so kindly add order by clause in query, it will solve your issue.
you can try below configuration, it's working.

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://ip:5432/dbname"
jdbc_user => "postgres"
jdbc_password => "postgres"
jdbc_driver_library => "/postgresql.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
jdbc_paging_enabled => true
jdbc_page_size => 25000
statement => "select * from source_table order by id desc"
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "localhost:9200"
index => "sample"
document_type => "docs"
document_id => "%{id}"
}
}
```